# Css transform scale based on container width

Tags: css, iframe

I want to display an iframe at a fixed sized 1440px but scale that into a container on my page. I can get it to work with a fixed number e.g.

```
.scaled {
  width: 1440px;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: 0,0;
}
```

However is it possible to scale this to fit it's parent container where the container is a percentage width e.g.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="column"> 
        .... some content
   </div>

   <div class="column">
       <iframe src="...blah" class="scaled" />
   </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Further description

So the ideal outcome here is to have the column being 50% of the row where the row width can vary with the viewport e.g. 900px, 1440px etc...

However, I want to have the iframe taking up the entire column width and displaying as though it were in a 1440px viewport. (Hence the width 1440px and scale transformation)

Unfortunately, this is **invalid** code as you cannot divide by a pixel length but something like this:

```
.scaled-proportion {
    width: 1440px;
    transform: scale(calc(100% / 1440px));
    transform-origin: 0,0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @AkashPinnaka I have added more detail to the question

Comment: You want the iframe to take double the length of parent? i.e.,  `.column`

Comment: @AkashPinnaka no the iframe is the width of the parent. But it shows the content viewport as though it is at 1440px (regardless of the size of the iframe size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read from [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) and have also figured out yourself,

> [In `calc()`'s division] The right-hand side must be a [<number>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number).

Unfortunately, this means that this function cannot be used with two `px`/`%` values.
calc() was probably our only alternative to JavaScript, and, in absence of that, we'll have to use just that.

You can [read the full guide at CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/#article-header-id-1), or you can see a working example provided by them [here](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/VvRoWy).